# JSON to PowerShell help needed

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to get some exchange rates through API but I do not know how to transform all this to one table like:

```
date | timestamp | base | Currency Name | Currency |
```

I need rates to expand in two columns Currency Name and Currency?

```bsh
$request = website
$X = Invoke-WebRequest $request
$JSONResult = $x | ConvertFrom-Json
$JSONResult
```

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1519296206,
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2018-06-12",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 1.566015,
        "CAD": 1.560132,
        "CHF": 1.154727,
        "CNY": 7.827874,
        "GBP": 0.882047,
        "JPY": 132.360679,
        "USD": 1.23396,
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to transform JSON into tables. 

For example, with PostgreSQL, you can use COPY to get contents of a JSON file to a JSON column. Then, you use Postgre's JSON functions to get values from the JSON column.

Also, you could have a Java application consuming a JSON and taking its attributes to a table.

So, you need to know how you want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output of:

```
> $JSONResult

success   : True
timestamp : 1519296206
base      : EUR
date      : 2018-06-12
rates     : @{AUD=1,566015; CAD=1,560132; CHF=1,154727; CNY=7,827874; GBP=0,882047; JPY=132,360679; USD=1,23396}
```

you could have derived how to put it together:

```
$request = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=hexkeydeletedhexkeydeletedhexkey'
$x= Invoke-WebRequest $request 
$JSONResult = $x | ConvertFrom-Json 
If ($JSONResult.success){ 
  $JSONResult.rates.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { 
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{ 
    'date' = $JSONResult.date 
    'timestamp' = $JSONResult.timestamp 
    'base' = $JSONResult.base 
    'Currency Name' = $_.Name 
    'Currency' = $_.Value } 
  } | select date,timestamp,base,'Currency Name',Currency|ft -auto 
}
```

Sample output:

```
date        timestamp base Currency Name   Currency
----        --------- ---- -------------   --------
2018-06-12 1519296206 EUR  AUD             1,566015
2018-06-12 1519296206 EUR  CAD             1,560132
2018-06-12 1519296206 EUR  CHF             1,154727
2018-06-12 1519296206 EUR  CNY             7,827874
2018-06-12 1519296206 EUR  GBP             0,882047
2018-06-12 1519296206 EUR  JPY           132,360679
2018-06-12 1519296206 EUR  USD              1,23396
```

---

To convert timestamp from unix datetime format to localtime you can use this function

```
Function Convert-FromUnixDate ($UnixDate) {
   [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($UnixDate))
}
```

---

```
> (Convert-FromUnixDate 1528900809):ToString('G')
2018-06-13 16:40:09
```

Comment: Hello LotPings, I appreciate your respond, I'm still facing small issue can you please check am I missing something here. '$request = 'http://domain'
$X= Invoke-Web Request $request
$JSONResult = $x | ConvertFrom-Json
If ($JSONResult.success){ $JSONResult.rates.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
 'date'          = $JSONResult.date 
 'timestamp'     = $JSONResult.timestamp
  'base'          = $JSONResult.base
 'Currency Name' = $_.Name
  'Currency'      = $_.Value } }   | select date,timestamp,base,'Currency Name',Currency|ft -auto}

Comment: At line:15 char:5
+     | select date,timestamp,base,'Currency Name',Currency|ft -auto
+     ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: As I do not have an URL to feed the data from I took your json sample as a here string and removed the comma after `"USD": 1.23396,` and the `[...]`

Comment: Please try this one it works without access key                                $request = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest'

Comment: That doesn't work, it returns `$JSONResult.success = False` and `$JSONResult.error.type = missing_access_key` . Why don't you edit your question to contain a more complete response and the error you get?

Comment: You seem to insert a wrong space in `Invoke-WebRequest` without that the script runs fine here. That's why I suggested to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50825339/edit) your question to contain additional information. Code in comments is hardly readable.

Comment: Good that you deleted the comment with key, I have deleted it too, after having checked once that the code run's fine.

Comment: LotPings, would you mind post the code what you have fixed that shows you the results in table format. I checked the Invoke-WebRequest and still the result are displaying:<br\>                                                                               `date     : 2018-06-13<br\>
Currency     : 4.324884<br\>
timestamp     : 1528897509<br\>
Currency Name : AED<br\>
base   :EUR`

Comment: It's excatly the code above, just reinsert your proper key.

Comment: Awesome it works perfectly now. I appreciate the time you spent to respond.

Answer (score 3):

After the conversion the value of the `rates` property of your JSON data is a custom object with the currency names as properties and the exchange rates(?) as their value. Use the intrinsic property `PSObject` of that object to enumerate the object properties and their values:

```
$JSONResult.rates.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Date'          = $JSONResult.date
        ...
        'Currency Name' = $_.Name
        'Currency'      = $_.Value
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Ansgar,  Thank you for your time to respond, I'm so new to powershell  and would you please be able to give me full code that will show me all the columns. I'm having difficulties combining the code together thank you so much

Comment: @Nehat I expanded my code snippet a little to give you an idea of how to integrate the other properties. If you still find yourself unable to integrate it with the rest of your code I recommend finding a PowerShell tutorial first.